# WooCommerce, WP 4.9.7 update product attribute after order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a product what have attribute `limited-edition-counter`. When someone will buy this product I need to increment this attribute.

I tried to use  `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', _my_function, 10, 1);`

but it isn't called after order. It's only one trigger what I found to call after each order. 
I use own plugin to extends WP.

Any hints how can I solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `woocommerce_thankyou` hook so it will call everytime when someone order from the store.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'your_function' );

function your_function() 
{
  //access `limited-edition-counter` attribute here and increment it here
}
```